# Reordenar filas y almacenar posicion mysql jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

Tengo mi base de datos:

```
id_producto|producto|id_auto_generado
1233255    |atun 1  |1
1243222    |atun 2  |2
1252321    |atun 3  |3
1263213    |atun 4  |4
```

y muestro mi tabla con php y mysql como es comun, ahora bien lo que deseo es mediante jquery poder arrastrar un  y reordenar su posicion, y luego de ello automaticamente me almacene la nueva posicion en mysql y al volver a cargar se mantenga

lo que e tratado:

1. crear un nuevo campo en mi base de datos con el nombre orden, y al arrastrar el tr escanea la posicion de todos los tr y los guarda pero esto es bastante lento y muy poco versatil

ustedes tendran alguna recomendacion porfavor? gracias.

Comment: Saludos. Agrega tu código HTML así como el Javascript (por lo que veo usas el jQuery) para ver lo que estas haciendo y poder sugerirte que hacer.

Comment: no se como empezar en jquery esta funcion amigo :(